# How to add nil value to Swift Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, null, option-type

I have made a request to my server in my app. And posted data something like this.Server side is waiting for all parameters even they are nil. But i couldn't add nil values to dictionary.

```
 var postDict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
 postDict[pass]=123
 postDict[name]="ali"
 postDict[surname]=nil // dictionary still has only pass and name variables.
```

Is there a way to add nil value to dictionary ?

Comment: When you assign `nil` to a key, it **will** return `nil` next time you access that key (because it removes the object and the removed object is not there). If you want to represent a non-`nil` null value, you can use `NSNull()`.

Comment: use [NSNull null] or nothing.

Comment: This isn't even a swift question; putting NSNull instances in a dictionary to represent empty values is part of Foundation.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

> How to add `nil` value to Swift Dictionary?

Basically the same way you add any other value to a dictionary. You first need a dictionary which has a value type that can hold your value. The type `AnyObject` cannot have a value `nil`. So a dictionary of type `[String : AnyObject]` cannot have a value `nil`.

If you had a dictionary with a value type that was an optional type, like `[String : AnyObject?]`, then it can hold `nil` values. For example,

```
let x : [String : AnyObject?] = ["foo" : nil]
```

If you want to use the subscript syntax to assign an element, it is a little tricky. Note that a subscript of type `[K:V]` has type `V?`. The optional is for, when you get it out, indicating whether there is an entry for that key or not, and if so, the value; and when you put it in, it allows you to either set a value or remove the entry (by assigning `nil`).

That means for our dictionary of type `[String : AnyObject?]`, the subscript has type `AnyObject??`. Again, when you put a value into the subscript, the "outer" optional allows you to set a value or remove the entry. If we simply wrote

```
x["foo"] = nil
```

the compiler infers that to be `nil` of type `AnyObject??`, the outer optional, which would mean remove the entry for key `"foo"`.

In order to *set* the value for key `"foo"` to the `AnyObject?` value `nil`, we need to pass in a non-`nil` outer optional, containing an inner optional (of type `AnyObject?`) of value `nil`. In order to do this, we can do

```
let v : AnyObject? = nil
x["foo"] = v
```

or

```
x["foo"] = nil as AnyObject?
```

Anything that indicates that we have a `nil` of `AnyObject?`, and not `AnyObject??`.

Comment: This solution is so much more Swifty than `NSNull()`!

Comment: It's a little easier to use and more readable if you define this "Null" object as a constant:`static let NullObject: AnyObject?? = Optional(nil)`

Comment: Whose bright idea was it that assigning nil to a dictionary entry means remove the entry, even when nil is a valid entry when the dictionary is defined as having AnyObject? or Any? entries? That just cost me several hours and lowered my opinion of Swift a couple of notches.

Comment: The correct answer is the one from Guiller, by setting nil a value using subscript you remove the value anche the key, while using the function `updateValue` you can set the value to nil while keeping the key.

Comment: Good point. It's confusing, but the point is indeed use `= nil as Foo?`.

Comment: x["foo"] = nil will delete the entry "foo". x["foo"]! = nil will se the value of the entry "foo" to nil. x["bar"] = nil will not insert any entry. x["bar"]! = nil will blow up. x.updateValue( nil, forKey: "bar" ) will add entry "bar" to x with value nil, as pointed in the @Guiller answer.

Comment: x["foo"] = nil as Any? also works. But I think updateValue(nil, forKey: "foo") is easier to understand for people who is junior or getting started with swift.

Answer (score 60):

You can use the `updateValue` method:

```
postDict.updateValue(nil, forKey: surname)
```

Comment: Dont know why this is downvoted but this is the best way to do it imho.

Comment: This is the best answer I have ever seen on SA. You should be gifted with 1 million battles of wine;) I have created a bounty and I will award it to you within 24 hours;)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: Then you should have chosen *"One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."* as the bounty reason. Now it looks as if you are looking for another/better answer.

Comment: @MartinR you are right, I would change the reason of bounty but I cannot. Nice learn to me;)

Answer (score 26):

As [documented in here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary#2846229), setting `nil` for a key in dictionary means removing the element itself.

If you want `null` when converting to `JSON` for example, you can use `NSNull()`

```
var postDict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
postDict["pass"]=123
postDict["name"]="ali"
postDict["surname"]=NSNull()

let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: nil)!
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
// -> {"pass":123,"surname":null,"name":"ali"}
```

Comment: This one should be an accepted answer as passing NSNull doesn't require the dictionary to have an optional value

Answer (score 5):

```
postDict[surname] = Optional<AnyObject>(nil)
```

Comment: In most (all?) cases you don't even need the `<AnyObject>`. It should be able to infer the type.

Answer (score 4):

> Below dictionary will hold one key with nil value

```
var dict = [String:Any?]()
dict["someKey"] = nil as Any?
```

Comment: This is a very right answer for setting `nil` value for a key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Optional` type

```
var postDict = ["pass": 123, "name": "ali", "surname": Optional()]
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a `nil` value to a dictionary in Swift, your dictionary's values must be of the `Optional` type.

Consider a `Person` class:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    weak var spouse: Person?

    init(name: String, spouse: Person?) {
        self.name = name
        self.spouse = spouse
    }
}
```

Instances of the `Person` type can have a `name` and an optional `spouse`.  Create two instances, and add the first to a dictionary:

```
let p1 = Person(name: "John", spouse: nil)
let p2 = Person(name: "Doe", spouse: p1)
p1.spouse = p2
var people = [p1.name: p1.spouse]
```

This dictionary (called `people`) maps names to spouses, and is of type `[String: Person?]`.  You now have a dictionary with a value of `Optional` type: `Person?`.

To update the value of the key `p1.name` to be `nil`, use the `updateValue(_: forKey:)` method on the `Dictionary` type.

```
people.updateValue(nil, forKey: p1.name)
people[p1.name]
```

The value for the key `p1.name` is now `nil`.  Using `updateValue(_: forKey:)` is a bit more straightforward in this case because it doesn't involve making a throwaway instance, setting it to `nil`, and assigning that instance to a key in a dictionary.

**NB:** See rintaro's answer for inserting `null` into a post's dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dict = [Int:Int?]()

dict[0] = (Int?).none // <--- sets to value nil

dict[0] = nil         // <-- removes

dict[0] = .none       // <-- same as previous, but more expressive

switch dict[0] {
case .none:
    Swift.print("Value does not exist")

case .some(let value):
    if let value = value {
        Swift.print("Value exists and is", value)
    } else {
        Swift.print("Value exists and is nil")
    }
}
```

Comment: First line should be `var dict = [Int: Int?]()`. It's a definition, not just a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

```
postDict[surname]=nil
```

When you use subscript to set nil. It deletes the key if exists. In this case key surname will be removed from dictionary if exists.

To set value as nil, there are certain ways.

```
postDict.updateValue(nil, forKey: surname)
```

or

```
let anyObjectNil : AnyObject? = nil
postDict[surname] = anyObjectNil
```

or

```
postDict[surname] = nil as AnyObject?
```