# Why is the nil coalescing operator ?? returning nil?

Tags: swift, option-type

Consider the following example involving the *nil coalescing operator* `??`:

```
let mysteryInc = ["Fred": "Jones", "Scooby-Doo": nil]

let lastname = mysteryInc["Scooby-Doo"] ?? "no last name"

print(lastname == nil)  // true
```

As shown by the last `print` statement, the result of the *nil coalescing operator* is `nil`.

If the *nil coalescing operator* is supposed to unwrap an *Optional*, why is it returning `nil`?

Comment: Related: [Check if key exists in dictionary of type `[Type:Type?]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299727/check-if-key-exists-in-dictionary-of-type-typetype)

Comment: Also, an interesting use case: `mysteryInc["Scooby-Doo"] = nil`. What will it do?

Comment: @Sulthan, `mysteryInc["Fred"] = nil` removes `Fred` entirely from the dictionary.  `mysteryInc["Fred"] = Optional(nil)` replaces "Jones" with `nil`.

Comment: Related [Checking for nil Value in Swift Dictionary Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018238/checking-for-nil-value-in-swift-dictionary-extension), [How to add nil value to Swift Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544573/how-to-add-nil-value-to-swift-dictionary)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To see what is going on here, assign the dictionary look up to a constant:

```
let name = mysteryInc["Scooby-Doo"]
print(type(of: name))
```

Output:

> ```
> Optional<Optional<String>>
> ```

So, `name` is a *double Optional*, a `String??`.

When the *nil coalescing operator* is applied, it unwraps the outer *Optional* and leaves an `Optional<String>` (aka `String?`).  In the example in the question, Swift treats the String literal `"no last name"` as type `String?` so that `??` can be applied.

If you examine the value of `name` you will find that it is `Optional(nil)`.  All dictionary look ups return *Optionals* because the *key* might not exist (in which case they return `nil`).  In this case, the `mysteryInc` dictionary is of type `[String: String?]`.  The value corresponding to `"Scooby-Doo"` is `nil` which then gets wrapped into an *Optional* (because of the dictionary look up) to become `Optional(nil)`.

Finally, the value `Optional(nil)` is unwrapped by `??`.  Since `Optional(nil) != nil`, Swift unwraps `Optional(nil)` and returns `nil` instead of returning the expected `"no last name"`.

And that is how you can get `nil` from the *nil coalescing operator*.  It did unwrap the *Optional*; there just happened to be a `nil` inside of that *Optional*.

---

As @LeoDabus noted in the comments, the correct way to deal with this situation is to *conditionally cast* the name to `String` before applying the *nil coalescing operator*:

```
let lastname = mysteryInc["Scooby-Doo"] as? String ?? "no last name"
```

In reality, it is best to avoid having *Optionals* as values for your dictionary for the very reason that @Sulthan raises:

What does `mysteryInc["Fred"] = nil` do?

Assigning `nil` to a dictionary entry removes that entry from the dictionary, so `mysteryInc["Fred"] = nil` doesn't replace `Optional("Jones")` with `nil`, it removes the `"Fred"` entry altogether.  To leave `"Fred"` in the dictionary and make his last name `nil`, you need to assign `mysteryInc["Fred"] = Optional(nil)` or `mysteryInc.updateValue(nil, forKey: "Fred")`.

Comment: You need to first cast as string then use the nil coalescing operator `as? String ?? "no last name"`

Comment: @LeoDabus, thanks for the suggestion.  Interestingly, this has only worked since Swift 3.1.  In Swift 3.02 and earlier it gives: **Error: downcast from 'String??' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!!'?**

Comment: You are welcome. regarding the prior syntax I have no Idea. I would never use an optional value type inside a Dictionary so I've never tried before. I generally use a struct.

Comment: BTW Interesting  the Optional(nil) stuff

Comment: I would probably prefer using `.updateValue` method directly instead of assigning `dict[key] = Optional(nil)`.

Comment: Yeah.  I typically avoid optional values in dictionaries as well.  In this example, it actually has a use.  `mysteryInc["Scooby-Doo"] == Optional(nil)` is `true` meaning `Scooby-Doo` is in `mysteryInc` but doesn't have a last name. `mysteryInc["Speed Buggy"] == nil` is true meaning `Speed Buggy` isn't in `mysteryInc`.